# Can we add a table to as a column of another table in SQLite Database?

Tags: android

I already have a table created - Student list. It has columns namely, the student's name, age, class, rank....and also notes that the teacher has made regarding the student. now i want this notes to refer another table. is it possible? if so please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but not the way you are asking. You can not add a full table as a column to another but can use [Foreign key concept](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) (introduced in sqlite 3.6.19 [AFAIK]) in such situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry. Thanks Cirag and Joshi for giving such strong support...just going through the foreign key concept.